# Can't unlink tar archive

Tags: php

First I create a tar archive than I compress it into gzip. After that I want to delete the tar archive but I get:

```
Warning: unlink(archive.tar): Permission denied in...
```

To test my permission on execute I created a zip archive, then unlink it and it worked. It seems that that tar archive is special...

Comment: Why did you tag your question *PHP*?

Comment: Because I created my archive with PharData and unlink is a Php method..

Comment: Please mention this in your question. Giving an outline of the system you're working in will help us answer your question.

Comment: I found the solution! I used unset on my PharData object then called Phar::unlinkArchive("archive.tar");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phar::unlinkArchive("archive.tar")

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.unlinkarchive.php)

Comment: and unset the object before this, i found this myself but thanks anyway